# API calls raise errors but return results

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I have a script that calls the asynchronous API. It calls the API at regular intervals until the results are available. I run this script from Jupyter Notebook.

The script saves the output correctly in JSON file, but it does not stop...
Also it throughs the following warning:

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

I know that it's possible to run `jupyter-notebook` using some additional commands to disable this warning. But even if I drop the line of code where I save the result to JSON (and this warning disappears), the script enters into a loop and does not stop (I was waiting 1 hour).

```
n_tries = 10
n_try = 0
wait_sec = 5
max_wait_sec = 60
while n_try < n_tries:
    try:
        resp = get(url = get_url, headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key})
        resp_json = resp.json()
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            print("GET results failed:\n%s" % json.dumps(resp_json))
            quit()
        status = resp_json["status"]
        if status == "succeeded":
            if output_path:
                with open(output_path, 'w') as outfile:
                    json.dump(resp_json, outfile, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
            print("Succeeded:\n%s" % json.dumps(resp_json, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
            quit()
        if status == "failed":
            print("Failed:\n%s" % json.dumps(resp_json))
            quit()   
        # Still running. Wait and retry.
        time.sleep(wait_sec)
        n_try += 1
        wait_sec = min(2*wait_sec, max_wait_sec) 
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "GET results failed:\n%s" % str(e)
        print(msg)
        quit()
    
print("The operation did not complete within the allocated time.")
```

Any ideas why it happens? Is there any way to fix it?

P.S. The API works well through the UI. The problems only happen when I call it in Jupyter Notebook with Python.

Comment: Add `resp.raise_for_status()` to trigger HTTPError

Comment: @GuiHva: Thanks. Where exactly do you recommend to add this line?

Comment: `resp.raise_for_status()` # to catch Exception
Add to `resp=get()` next line